# How to hide language selector dropdown on node add page for a role?

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I would like to hide the language selector dropdown on node add pages of multilanguage enabled content types.

What would be the best way? A jquery selector perhaps?

Comment: I would not recommend jQuery selector because sometimes your client comes with a slow connection, and that will make the drop down to show while the page is loading, then it will disappear.

Comment: Ps I ended up using css http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/how-can-i-remove-language-selector-my-multilanguage-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use jQuery for this. Better use `hook_form_alter`.

Check if user has target role.
Print out your `$form` and find language select in printed array.
Than hide language select.

There are 2 options for hiding:

1st:

```
$form['language']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

2nd:

```
$form['language']['#prefix'] = '<div class="element-invisible">';
$form['language']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, the default block settings configuration page may be all you need.

Go to `admin/structure/blocks/manage` and edit the language selector box.  At the bottom of the screen, under **Pages**, set to show the block on *All pages except those listed* and then set the path to `node/*/edit`.  If you need more fine-grained control, you can use the PHP code option.

Answer (score 1):

First :

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
 ....
 $form['#after_build'][] = 'my_custom_form_after_build';
}
```

Second:

```
function my_custom_form_after_build(&$form, &$form_state){
 $form['language']['#access']=FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable it from drupal go to admin/config/regional/i18n/select

just tick "Hide content translation links"